# How do I remove the space between all of my sections on my webpage?

Tags: html, margin, padding

The problem I am having is when I resize my page it creates huge ape between the header and the navigation, and between the h1 and paragraph content. I am doing this for a school assignment and they gave me step by step instructions but even after I have followed them it created all of this space.

This is my CSS code for the webpage:

```
header, main, nav, footer, figure, figcaption, aside, section,
article { display: block; }

body {background-color: #3F2860;
      font-family: arial;
      color: #3F2860;
}
nav a:link {
    color: #3F2860;
}
nav a:visited {
    color: #497777;
}
nav a:hover{
    color: #A26100
}
nav a:hover{
    border: 3px inset #333333;
}
* {box-sizing: border-box; }
#wrapper{margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 80%;
        min-width: 550px;
        max-width: 1280px;
        background-color: #F5F5F5;
        color: #3F2860;        
}
header{height: 150px;
}
main{padding-bottom: 3em;
     padding-top: 0;
     padding-left: 3em;
     padding-right: 3em;
     display: block;
     margin-left: 170px;

}
#mathero{height: 300px;
        background-image: url(images/yogamat.jpg);
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
#loungehero{height: 300px;
           background-image: url(images/yogalounge.jpg);
           background-size: 100% 100%;
           background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#mobile{display: none;

}
#desktop{display: inline;

}
/*img{padding-left: 2em;
    padding-right: 2em;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}*/

nav{text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 1em;
    float: left;
    width: 190px;
}
nav > ul {
    padding-left: 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav a {text-decoration: none;
       display: block;
       text-align: center;
       font-weight: bold;
       border: 3px outset #CCCCCC;
       margin-bottom: 1em;
       padding: 1em;
}

li {font-size: 90%;    
}
h1 {background-color: #9BC1C2;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-left: 2em;
    background-image: url(images/lilyheader.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
}
footer {background-color: #9BC1C2;  
    text-align: center;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: small;
    padding: 1em;

}
.floatleft {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 4em;  
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
    padding-left: 15em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 64em){
    body{margin: 0;
         padding: 0;  
    } 
    #wrapper{min-width: 0;
             width: auto;
             margin: 0;
             padding: 0;
    }
    header{padding-top: 1px;
    }
    main{padding-top: 0;
        padding-bottom: 2.5em;
        padding-left: 1em;
        padding-right: 1em;
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 90%;
        clear: both;
    }
    nav{float: none;
        width: auto;
        padding-left: 2em;
    }   
    nav a{padding: .2em;
          margin-left: .3em;
          float: left;
          width: 23%;
    }
    h2, h3, p, dl{padding: 2em;
    }
    main ul{margin-left: 2em;   
    }
    .floatleft{margin-left: 2em;
               margin-bottom: 1em;
    }
    .clear{padding-left: 2em;   
    }
    mathero, loungehero{height: 150px;
     width: 80%;
     margin-left: auto; 
     margin-right: auto;}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 37.5em) {
    h1{font-size: 2em;
    padding-top: .25em;
    padding-left: 1.5em;
    width: 85%;
    text-align: center;}
    nav a{padding: 0.5em;
    width: 45%;
    float: left;
    min-width: 6em;
    margin-left: .5em;}
    li{font-size: 100%;}
    .floatleft{float: none;
    display: none;}
    mathero, loungehero{background-image: none;
    height: 0;}
    footer{padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0;}
    #mobile{display: inline;
    }
    #desktop{diplay:none;
    }
}
```

Html code for one of my pages:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
        <head>
            <link href="yoga.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
            <title>Path of Light Yoga Studio</title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="wrapper"> 
                <header>
                <h1>Path of Light Yoga Studio</h1>
                </header>    
                    <nav>
                        <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="classes.html">Classes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="schedule.html">Schedule</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                <main>
      <img src="images/yogadoor2.jpg" alt="Yoga Door" height="280" 


width="225" class="floatleft"/>
            <h2>Find Your Inner Light</h2> 
            <p>
      Path of Light Yoga Studio provides all levels of yoga practice 
in a tranquil, peaceful environment. Whether you are new to yoga or   an 
experienced practitioner, our dedicated instructors can develop a practice 
  to meet your needs. Let your inner light shine at the Path of Light 
             Yoga Studio.
            </p>
            <ul>
    <li>Hatha, Vinyasa, and Restorative Yoga classes</li>  
    <li>Drop-ins Welcome</li>  
    <li>Mats, blocks, and blankets provided</li>  
    <li>Relax in our Serenity Lounge before and after your class</li>  
            </ul>
        </main>
        <div class="clear">
            <p>
                612 Serenity Way <br>
                El Dorado, AZ 86336 <br>

            <a id="mobile" href="tel:888-555-5555">888-555-5555</a>
            <span id="desktop">888-555-5555</span>
            </p>
                </div>
        <hr>
        <footer>
            Copyright &copy; 2018 Path of Light Yoga Studio <br>
            This page was created by Audrey Boyd for IT2040, Section 004 Spring 2018, Lab #4
                    <br>
            <a href="mailto:boydau@mail.uc.edu">boydau@mail.uc.edu</a>
        </footer>
            </div>
            </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for providing your CSS, but can you please provide the relevant HTML as well? It's rather difficult to answer this question without being able to see how the page is rendered. It would help if you could update your question to list all **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If your HTML is generated server-side, could you please post the **output**. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Comment: I don't think there is a font called `ariel`. And if you don't want big gaps it might help if you don't instruct the browser to do these gaps.

Comment: Im sorry I am fairly new to HTML so I am very confused about a lot of things. I will add the rest of the HTML code so you can better understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to start, there is no font-family or font called "ariel." It is Arial. Secondly, it is hard for me to help you when you have not provided the HTML to the page. Could you please link that? I am putting this as an answer instead of a question since I don't have that privilege, but I will edit it to give you the answer once you describe it to me.